# JS TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror

I have situation as follows

```
function Field(data){
    var name = data.name;
    this.foo = function(){
        console.log("foo");    
    }
}
...
field = new Field(someData);
...
console.log(field.name); //returns its name as expected
field.foo(); //TypeError: field.foo is not a function
```

What's problem with that? I use it in angularjs application.

Im backend developer so please be understanding.

Comment: You never seem to set the `name` property of the initialized object. I am not sure then the presence of this property is expected. I guess then this is somehow related to the issue you ask about. Are you sure there isn't anything in the code that you haven't posted here? Like `return data` at the end of the constructor function?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ldp9gso/ foo method work as expected, it's `.name` that wouldbn't work with that code.

Comment: @GillesC How can you tell. You don't know what is getting passed in. Obviously if OP does not get an error with `.name` there is an object passed in with a name key. The problem at hand is that the variable created inside the function is a private variable.

Comment: Thanks guys, now I see that is something else, maybe my angularjs context. Thanks for snippet @GillesC

Comment: `var name` make it private to Field so it wouldn't be available publicly

Answer (score 1):

You will need to assign `name` to the current context (`this`).  However, the `foo()` function should be working as you have it in your question.  See this code snippet as a demonstration:

```js
function Field(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
  this.foo = function() {
    document.writeln('foo' + '<br />');
  }
}

var someData = { name: 'MyName' };
var field = new Field(someData);
document.writeln(field.name + '<br />');
field.foo();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks for snippet, it must be something with my angularjs context.